# Equivalent of the English "use to" structure in German

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I'd like to know how to translate English sentences like "I used to do it" to German proper; for instance:

> - I used to read those books.
> - He used to go the theatre often.

For example, are the following correct/meaningful in German?

> 1. Ich habe/hatte mich gewöhnt, es zu tun.
> 2. Ich bin/war gewöhnt, es zu tun.

Comment: There are different translations available in German. To give you the right one more context is needed.

Comment: You could improve your question by adding a number of "used to" examples (full sentences. The use of *used to* is pretty broad, and the German equivalents will be rather diverse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two distinct structures with *use to* in English, each with its own translation into German:

1. somebody *used to do* something

   > jemand *hat früher* etwas *getan*
   >   
   >   jemand *hat (ein)mal* etwas *getan*
   >   
   >   jemand *pflegte* etwas *zu tun*
   >   
   >   ...
2. to *get used to* something

   > *sich an* etwas *gewöhnen*

Even though your English sentence follows the first structure, your German example sentences are of the second structure.

Comment: The first one can be translated with the German phrase "zu tun pflegen" too. It sounds a bit outdated nowadays but it is still valid and understandable. In your example it would be "Er pflegte etwas zu tun". Especially in literature that is the best translation of "used to do something".

Comment: _used to to_ also does express some regularity. It can roughly be translated into german by _hat immer das gemacht_. Example: _We used to go to France during holiday._ translates to _Wir sind immer nach Frankreich in den Urlaub gefahren._

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Thank you for pointing this out. Even though the OP will certainly know this (because this regularity is also tacitly present in the English phrase), knowing about it allows one to translate the English phrase more flexibly.

Comment: Is this also proper:
_I used to_ = _Ich habe öfter gemacht, Ich habe (früher) immer gemacht_ ?